# What is the advantage of inserting a script-tag by using document.write() (for displaying individual advertsing)?

Tags: javascript, security

Obviously a lot of advertising people use document.write() for to insert additional scripts into a page.

For example:

```
var url = 'http://ads.com/buyme?rand=' + Math.random()
document.write('<script src="'+ url +'"></scr'+'ipt>')
```

What's the advantage of using these technique?

Why not writing `<script src="'http://ads.com/buymev?rand=123"></script>` into the HTML as usual? 
Or using document.createElement('script')?

What's the special benefit of using document.write() when I want to show someone advertising?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

document.write can append arbitrary, even partial, incomplete and malformed HTML into document.
It is very fast, because the browser doesn’t have to modify an existing DOM structure.

A great link http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write